# I need to convert an object array to a string array but it keep returning a null pointer

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i'm trying to collect data from my Firebase Database, store it in an ArrayList, Convert that ArrayList to an Object array then convert that to a String Array.

My code pretty much works until i try to convert my ArrayList to an Object Array then i get a null pointer.

```
public class PostSkillsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> skills_array;
    Object[] mySkills;
    public String[] skills;
    private AutoCompleteTextView jobInputSkills;
    private Button finishBtn;
    private ImageButton addSkillsBtn;
    private GridView gridView;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseSkills;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_skills);

        mDatabaseSkills = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Skills");
        mDatabaseSkills.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabaseSkills.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                collectSkills((Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });

        jobInputSkills = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.input_job_skills);
        finishBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skills_finish_btn);
        addSkillsBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_skills_btn);

        addSkillsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                didTapButton(v);
                addSkill();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Populate Skills Auto Text View
         */
        mySkills = skills_array.toArray();
        skills = Arrays.copyOf(mySkills, mySkills.length, String[].class);;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, skills);
        jobInputSkills.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * GridView Functionality
         */
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new SkillsAdapter(this, skills));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label))
                                .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void collectSkills(Map<String,Object> skills) {

        skills_array = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = skills.keySet().iterator();
        while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            String value=(String)skills.get(key);
            skills_array.add(value);
        }
    }

    private void addSkill() {
        String[] words = jobInputSkills.getText().toString().split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (words[0].length() > 0) {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[0].charAt(0)) + words[0].subSequence(1, words[0].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
            for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
                sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)) + words[i].subSequence(1, words[i].length()).toString().toLowerCase());
            }
        }
        final String skill_name = sb.toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(skill_name)){
            final DatabaseReference newSkill = mDatabaseSkills.child(skill_name);

            newSkill.child(skill_name).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    }
                    else {
                        newSkill.setValue(skill_name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
        }
    }

    public void didTapButton(View view) {
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.add_skills_btn);
        final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);

        // Use bounce interpolator with amplitude 0.2 and frequency 20
        MyBounceInterpolator interpolator = new MyBounceInterpolator(0.2, 20);
        myAnim.setInterpolator(interpolator);

        button.startAnimation(myAnim);
    }

    public class SkillsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private final String[] skillValues;

        public SkillsAdapter(Context context, String[] skillValues) {
            this.context = context;
            this.skillValues = skillValues;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View gridView;

            if (convertView == null) {

                gridView = new View(context);

                // get layout from mobile.xml
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skills_item, null);

                // set value into textview
                TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.label);
                textView.setText(skillValues[position]);

                // set image based on selected text
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.remove_skill_btn);

                String skill = skillValues[position];

            } else {
                gridView = (View) convertView;
            }

            return gridView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return skillValues.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's my Firebase Database. I need to store all the values for the children in an array to populate the AutoTextView.

```
Skills:
 Android:"Android"
 C++ Programming:"C++ Programming"
 Carpentry:"Carpentry"
 Electrician:"Electrician"
 HTML:"HTML"
 Housework:"Housework"
```

Update:
The error is on line 78. That starts with

```
mySkills = skills_array.toArray();
```

The skills_array should contain values from the function

```
private void collectSkills(Map<String,Object> skills) {

            skills_array = new ArrayList<>();

            Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = skills.keySet().iterator();
            while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
                String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
                String value=(String)skills.get(key);
                skills_array.add(value);
            }
        }
```

The logs I got are below.

```
02-21 20:34:32.647 4153-4153/com.example.android.oddjobs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.oddjobs, PID: 4153
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.oddjobs/com.example.android.oddjobs.PostSkillsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.ArrayList.toArray()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.ArrayList.toArray()' on a null object reference
at com.example.android.oddjobs.PostSkillsActivity.onCreate(PostSkillsActivity.java:78)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
02-21 20:34:34.022 4153-4239/com.example.android.oddjobs 

E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xaf9bb6c0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x9a87820c arg=0x0
    02-21 20:34:34.022 4153-4239/com.example.android.oddjobs E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xaf9bb6c0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Comment: Please add a stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just fixed the post.

Comment: What is line 78 of PostSkillsActivity.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ValueListeners in Firebase are asynchronous, meaning that they won't block the code that adds them.  In your code, it looks like you're assuming that the listener will be invoked immediately.  Instead, what's actually happening is that your onCreate method is continuing after you add the listener, which means that skills_array remains uninitialized (null) when it's accessed.

You should wait until the listener actually gets invoked in order to update your UI with the data that gets collected from it.  You can't do that during onCreate.

Comment: Synchronous vs. asynchronous is not really the issue. Understanding events and listeners is. (Just nit picking wording here...the content of your answer is generally correct.)

Comment: The authors of the Firebase docs felt that it was an important distinction to note from the outset: "Firebase data is written to a FirebaseDatabase reference and retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener to the reference." https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the feedback. How ex the exactly do i ensure that the ValueEventListener will be invoked first. So far, i've tried moving the code to update data to the onStart() method and to the function collectSkills but it hasn't worked yet.

Comment: Yes, the listener is asynchronous in this case. However, no listeners are called immediately when they are added, no matter the threading model used.

Comment: It's important to state in order to avoid possible confusion between event notifications, which are async, vs state notifications, which *could* be synchronous.  Stating up front that it's async clarifies this distinction without question.